# GLTF file 404 not found

Tags: javascript, three.js, gltf

So I'm trying to load a GLTF file and I am receiving this error:
[image]

I don't know why it can't locate and open the file. Do I have to set up a local server? 
I looked up other examples online and [this one](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/webgl_animation_keyframes.html) includes a DRACOLoader. Admittedly, I don't know what this is for and was wondering if I need to implement this in order for it to load.

Here is my code:

```
<html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Website first attempt</title>


        <style>
            body { margin: 0;
                background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33ccff 0%, #ffffff 20%);}
            canvas { display: block; }
        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

      <!-- <script type = "module" src="build/myScript.js"></script>-->
       <script type = "module">
        import * as THREE from '../build/three.module.js';

          import { GLTFLoader } from '../build/GLTFLoader.js';

            let scene, camera, renderer, hlight;


            function init () {
                //scene
                scene = new THREE.Scene();

                //camera
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth/ window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);

                //light
                hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight (0x404040, 100);
                scene.add(hlight);


                //render                
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
                renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 0 );
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

                document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

                //3d
                let loader = new GLTFLoader();
                loader.load('assets/londonmap.gltf', function(gltf){
                    scene.add(gltf.scene);

                })


            }


            function onWindowResize () {

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                }

                window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);

            function animate () {

                requestAnimationFrame(animate);

                render();

            }

            function render() {

                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }

            init ();
            animate();


       </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DracoLoader` is only necessary if the `glTF` asset was compressed with the same-named compression algorithm.

A HTTP 404 means that it was not possible to load the file (in your case `assets/londonmap.gltf`) from the given path. So you have to make sure that the asset is actually present in the respective directory.

And yes, it's highly recommended to work with a local web server. Especially to avoid any security related browser issues. The project actually provides a small guide about this topic: [How to run things locally](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/How-to-run-things-locally).

Comment: Thank your for your answer. So I have included the image within the same folder as my index as well just in case it can't find the folder 'assets' but it still is not possible to load it. I have tried other gltf files from the internet as well just in case something was wrong with my file but it still has the same error. I have made a local server and it didn't help. I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Consider to share you project as a github repository so it's easier to see what you are doing.

Comment: Ah sorry I realized the issue was my export from blender. I didn't realise I needed three files for it despite having no texture. Thank you though @Mugen87.