# '404 not found' error when loading .glb/.gltf file

Tags: javascript, three.js, quasar

I created a model in Blender and saved it as `.glb` file. When I try to load it to Three.js (using Vue.js and to be precise Trois.js) then I encounter some `404 (not found)` error. Seems like path is wrong but I tried every single option to make proper relative path, however none of them works. Have no idea what's wrong. Here is my code:

**BaseModel.vue**

```
<template>
    <Renderer ref="renderer" 
      antialias 
      resize=true
      shadow
      :orbit-ctrl="{ enableDamping: true, target }"
      >
      <Camera ref="camera" :position="camera.position" />
      <Scene ref="scene" :background='bg_color'>
        <PointLight ref="light1" 
            :intensity="scene.pointLight.intensity"
            :position="scene.pointLight.position" />
        <GltfModel src="~assets/test.glb" />
      </Scene>
    </Renderer>
</template>
```

and my directory:

[image]

I also tried `~/assets/test.glb`, `/src/assets/test.glb`, `../../assets/test.glb` but in vain.
Always the same error:

[image]

I also checked this issues but it didn't help: [GLTF file 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60417384/gltf-file-404-not-found)

**EDIT:** I'm adding folders structure taken from dev tools, I can't see 'text'glb' model loaded to assets folder where I normally store it. Seems it hasn't been loaded, don't know why. And yes, I refreshed the sources (Ctrl+R)

[image]

Comment: Which folder are you running localhost in?

Comment: Default path ('/') points out to MainLayout.vue located in 'layouts' folder, as you can see in the screenshot above. I'm wondering if it has sth to do with webpack. Maybe .glb model can not be bundled as images do. Or maybe it's a matter of folder directory where I put my model in.

Comment: If you launch 3d model straight from absolute url, does it work? Try changing your url to absolute. Check my similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71011987/404-not-found-glf-gltf-model-is-not-loading-three-js-webpack-wordpress

Comment: I tried to figure out how to set absolute url but I'm not sure how to create it properly. I can't see any .glb file in 'assets' folder in dev tools 'sources' panel (as well as 'network'). Seems like this file hasn't loaded at all. When I start my app my url looks like http://localhost:8080/#/. I tried with http://localhost:8080/#/assets/test.glb but got 304 error  in return. I added tree from dev tools to my main topic to show there's no 'test.glb' model loaded.

Comment: If you can't see it in devtools, then your site isn't gonna receive the model

Comment: QUestion is why I can't see it..